# Simultaneous Report downloading issue in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

Am **working in asp.net web application and sql server as database**. In this we downloading the report for location details as excel sheet (every location it created new excel sheet) and place it in one folder which is happening nicely.The issue is many user will accessing the web application and downloading the report,
**if any user simultaneously downloading means it is downloading for one user only for the other user the downloading process get halt.**

ACTIONS TAKEN :- 1)increased timeout.
                 2)changing MAXDOP in sqlserver as per cores in server.
                 3)connections closed 
                 4) changed the debug attribute into false for better gc. 
                 5)Re-indexing

Any other suggestions to defend this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Check locking - 2 makes NO SENSE because multiple queries CAN execute at the same time, unless someone was challenged in not using exclusive or serializing locking for reporting (which should have READCOMITTED hints on the queries).

Generally find the issue. From your question it is not even clear whether it is SQL Server that is bottlenecking - can it be your excel use on the server (which, btw., is totally NOT SUPPORTED - running office on a server) is inherently single threaded? Why do you even blame SQL Server given the information you give, which indicates no real debug hints (as can be seen on the attempt to blame GB or reindexing both which will not result in any paralellism on the SQL side to start with). WIth the same reasonin you give I can advice you to eat vegan from now on and check whether it increases reporting performance. That is as sensible as just changing debug attribute or maxdop for something that incidentally should not happen like that to start with.

Start with analysis. Find out whether your SQL Server is even to blame. MAXDOP should always be configured to sensible value. Timeout? Seems your queries are POORLY OPTIMIZED. Unless you do what I do - which is stastistical analysis over a 3 billion row table - you should not have a serious issue IF your queries are sensible. This indicates serious query issues.

Comment: ah @tom thanks for your comment. as simple as that  user cannot downloading the report simultaneously and FYI, we downloaded in csv format. p.s: if the question is clumpsy , please edit my question. Thanks

Comment: I can not edit your question into making more sense because I do now know what you really ask here. Start baseline debugging - seriously. This i NOT a sql issue and you are a total failure as a programmer in as far as it seems you have not done ANY steps to find out which of your application parts actually are responsible. Instead you blame the database - which, unless the developer was truly incompetent (global lock, table exclusive lock forced) is most likely not to blame. Start some homework - find out WHERE the application stalls. If you think it is SQL - collect data to proove it.